# how can I count the amount of duplicate rows with this IF statement?

Tags: excel

I have a formula that vertically concatenates a columns duplicate rows into one cell. I then have a helper column to place the word `Last` in the last row of duplicate data before the next block of duplicates start.

Here's the formula: `=IF(A2<>A3,"Last","")`

Instead of having the word `Last` populate in the last row of data for that block, is there a way to replace that helper column word with a `#` stating the number of duplicate rows for that employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A2,$A2)
```

This counts how many values match the current cell. Just add it into your existing formula like this:

```
=IF($A2<>$A3,COUNTIFS($A$1:$A2,$A2),"")
```

**EDIT**

Please note that this counts the number of PREVIOUS values (including the current cell). If you want to count ALL the occurrences in the entire column, just change:

```
$A$1:$A2
```

to

```
$A:$A
```

Comment: no, the first one worked tremendously, thank you so much!